# How to explore features of strings PYTHON

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I have a table with relative abundances of strings collected elsewhere. I also have a list of features that are associated with the strings. What is the best way to explore each string for each feature and sum the relative abundancies.

Example Input Table:

```
+────────────+────────────+
| String     | Abundance  |
+────────────+────────────+
| abcdef     | 12         |
| cdefgh     | 15         |
| fghijk     | 36         |
| jklmnoabc  | 37         |
+────────────+────────────+
```

Example String Features:

```
cdef, abc, jk
```

Example Output

```
+──────────+────────────────+
| Feature  | Abundance (%)  |
+──────────+────────────────+
| cdef     | 27             |
| abc      | 59             |
| jk       | 73             |
+──────────+────────────────+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using any library? Where did you get stuck exactly? Without these questions being addressed, this question becomes slightly vague. You may want to include your attempts, and ask specific question based on your attempt and/or issue you faced.

Comment: Thank you ThePyGY. You are right, I realise I have left much unanswered! Essentially, so far I have tried putting each feature into a dictionary with the key being the string and the value being the percentage and iterating over each for each string. However, this is taking a lot longer to run that I thought it would and it is very bulky (in terms of lines of code). I was just wondering whether there is one quick fix for string searching that would solve all my problems. I realise coding is rarely like that though but I was hoping for a more sophisticated solution to my problem.

Comment: You should Edit your question, and include the code you tried in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to go through the list of string feature for each string you have and use the `in`operator of Python.
This will check if your feature has an occurence in the string you apply it to.
You then want to accumulate abundance and associate it to your feature.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do a loop with a regex? Because, you must go through your two lists (inputs and features). I don't think there is a particular algorithm to highly accelerate the process.

Here is what I'm thinking about

```
import re

for feature in features:
    p = re.compile(f"{feature.string}")
    feature.abundance = 0
    for input in inputs:
        m = p.match(input.string)
        if m: # if not None
           feature.abundance += input.abundance
```

With that, you will have all your stuff in your `features` list.